# Грамотный вывод данных из бд mysqli. Как оптимизировать запрос?

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть страница. На ней я разместил несколько запросов к БД.
В данном случае я делаю запрос к одной базе данных. В ней есть две таблицы - users и proza

- в users - имена и фото пользователей сайта
- в proza - статьи с    названиями

В итоге должно вывестись: 6 картинок с именами пользователей и ниже 10 карточек статей.
**Все работает**, но по-моему в следствии этого запроса идет высокая нагрузка на базу. Как лучше оптимизировать эти два запроса? может их лучше объединить в один?

и правильно ли  закрывать запрос таким способом: $conn->close();    и заново делать запрос к БД

Не оценивайте строго - я только новичок в php и mysql, просто прошу совета, так как из-за моих корявых запросов идет высокая нагрузка на БД :)

```
Лучшие авторы:

    <div class='scrollmenu'>


    require "conect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT id,name,type,img FROM users ORDER  BY RAND() LIMIT 6  ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "  <a href='read_stih?are=".$row['type']."' title='".$row['name']."'><img  src='imgdf/".$row['img']."'/><br><b>".$row['name']."</b></a>";
    }
    } 
    else {
        echo "Ничего нового....";
    }
    $conn->close();     
    
    
    
    echo "</div><div class='scrolltop'></div><br><center><b itemprop='author'>Статьи пользователей</b><br><br></center>";   
        
    require "conect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM proza WHERE type='$ar' ORDER  BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
    echo "<div><a href='reading?id=".$row['id']."&t=proza'><center><b>".$row['name']."</b></center><br>".$row['text']." <br><br><b> читать дальше...</b></a></div>";
}
} 


$conn->close();
```

Comment: А исходя из чего Вы решили, что идет высокая нагрузка на базу? У Вас 2 запроса - это максимум несколько десятков миллисекунд.

Comment: а так вообще можно делать? просто часто смотрел исходный код сайтов-примеров и там такие запросы объединяли

Comment: Так всё сильно зависит от того, что Вы хотите сделать. У Вас сейчас 2 независимых логических куска, сначала просто 6 пользователей, а дальше просто 10 статей. Будь у Вас 6 пользователей, и для каждого из них требовалось бы вывести по их 10 статей - можно было бы уже что-то объединять.

Comment: подключение закрывать и открывать заново, конечно, не надо. из корявости в ваших запросах - `rand()`, который в целом на небольших таблицах особо плохо не сделает, `select *`, который в принципе в небольшой базе тоже не криминал, но один раз просто приучитесь * не использовать. незачем лишние данные таскать между БД и приложением. Ну а в целом, объединить запросы, как выше уже написано тут возможности никакой нет, ибо они независимы